# unable to display jsp data in table

Tags: java, jsp

I've the below JSP

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <th>Patient ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Disease</th>
            <th>Doctor Assigned</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Room Assigned</th>
        </thead>

        <%
            String Query = "Select ID, Name, address, contactnumber,disease,DOCASSIGN,JOINING, ROOMASSIGN from patient";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%
                    out.print(rs.getInt(1));
                %>
            </td>
            <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
```

I'm running the query and get the data into a table `td`. The query is running fine the problem is if i take `<td><%out.print(rs.getInt(1));%></td>`, then the value is displayed in `td`, but when i'm trying to get it using `<td><%rs.getInt(1);%></td>`, the `td` is showing blank.

I want to know if in jsp, to display value, we have to use `out.print()` for sure, or i can display the value directly using `<td><%rs.getInt(1);%></td>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic ways to display values in JSP. First, as you noted, you can execute code between `<%` and `%>`. If you use `out.print` or `out.println` there, it will be displayed on your page:

```
<% out.print(rs.getInt(1)); %>
```

Alternatively, you can have an expression between `<%=` and `%>` (note the `=`!). This expression will simply be printed to the page:

```
<%= rs.getInt(1) %>
```